# Remove a style from a class in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a input tag with this class that get it from kendostyle

```
<input class="k-textbox k-input" >
```

and the k-input class is:

```
.k-input{
    height: 2.214em;
    line-height: 2.214em;
    padding: .177em 0;
    text-indent: .8em;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Now, I don't want the style

```
height: 2.214em;
```

In this class , how can I do this?

I can't edit this class is css file because it is used in some other tags

Comment: override it with your custom css.

Comment: That isn't how CSS works. You should add a more specific selector that applies the more specific style.

Comment: $('.k-textbox.k-input').css('height', '');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want style for particular line, you can use inline css to

override the css

```
<input class="k-textbox k-input"  style="height: auto;">
```

Answer (score 2):

add this way other css

```
.k-textbox.k-input{height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

add parent div then style like

```
<div class="parent">
  <input class="k-textbox k-input" >
</div>

.parent > .k-input{
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the property to an empty string appears to do the job.

```
$(".k-input").css("height", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

@user2830448 Please check following code as per your requirement. You can change height in first input as much you require:

```css
.k-input{
    height: 2.214em;
    line-height: 2.214em;
    padding: .177em 0;
    text-indent: .8em;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.custom_parent .k-input{
    height:auto !Important;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_parent">
    <input  type="text" class="k-textbox k-input" >
</div>  

<input class="k-textbox k-input" >
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add once static div and wrap text box in div.**

**Try this..**

```
<div class="cstm-input">
<input class="k-textbox k-input" />
</div>


div.cstm-input .k-input{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

**You can do this by jQuery also..**

I hope it's help for you...